# How to differentiate between got and receive

Tags: sentence-meaning, perfect-constructions

If I ask someone "have you got my email?", is it wrong? Or should I ask "have you received my email?"

Which one is gramatically correct, and other than this scenario, how do we differentiate these words for other sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "have you got" and "have you received" are correct. However, there is a difference in meaning.

I assume your intent is to ask about reception of an email *message*. With "have you received", this is the only logical meaning.

"Have you got" can also mean "do you have". For some styles of English this is the only meaning; ["have got" is equivalent to "have", and is not the present perfect of "get"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv323.shtml) (for the latter, "have gotten" can be used instead, but this is limited to American English). For many speakers, "have you got my email" would be interpreted as "do you have my email", which typically refers to the email *address*. To avoid ambiguity, you can use "did you get my email" or, if present perfect is important, "have you received".

Some guides recommend [using "have" instead of "have got" in formal writing](https://web.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/get-got.htm), but as indicated [here](http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-grammar/have-got), "have got" is very common in informal speech, especially in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

While 'receive' indicates the existence of a certain relationship between the receiver and sender, the word 'get' does not involve such ....

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Thanks for writing an answer. We expect our answers to be detailed and explanatory. Could you please expand on your answer a little and maybe tell us how that distinction applies to the sentence at issue?